# Solr 5.x with rails sunspot 2.2.3

Tags: solr, sunspot

I am running a rails 4 application wiht sunspot rails 2.2.3.
I just created a solr instance from scratch 5.2.1 and 5.3 .

Unfortunately the schema.xml which got generated by sunspot is not working in solr 5 it complains about datefield and any sortable number field e.g. sortableInt etc.
Has anyone managed to get sunspot running with solr 5 . A sample schema would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the latest schema file from GitHub repo - [schema.xml](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/schema.xml)

I'm using this schema and I'm able to get reindex running fine.